# springframework set custom reason phrase

Tags: spring, rest, http, spring-mvc

In a `@RestController` we have defined a custom ExceptionHandler using:

```
@ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
```

This works fine, however I also want to modify the "reason phrase" that this response will generate.

At the moment it always returns "404 Not Found"

I want to customise the "Not Found" text to something else.

How can I achieve this?

So what I want is to customise:

The text behind the red dod with "404" that currently says "Not Found". This is called the HTTP reason phrase.

[image]

Comment: Hi @seba.wagner I am trying to achieve the same thing, did you get any solution or workaround for this?

Comment: Just see the next answer that was given by @pczeus

Answer (score 3):

Trying to customize the HTTP/1.1 reason phrase might be pointless - there are no reason phrases in HTTP/2. So it would be short-sighted to use it for anything important.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason="Cuz I said so!")  // 404
```

I created a simple Spring Boot application (Using Groovy instead of Java). I created a very simple Rest Controller shown here:

```
@RestController
class TestController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    def there(){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("IAE Error")
    }

    @RequestMapping("testerror")
    @ExceptionHandler(IllegalArgumentException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason="Cuz I said so!")  // 404
   def testError(){
      "TestError"
    }
}
```

The response is a 404, with the following JSON returned:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1456972233805,
  "status": 404,
  "error": "Not Found",
  "exception": "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException",
  "message": "Cuz I said so!",
  "path": "/"
}
```

You can see that the 'reason' is returned as the 'message' in the JSON response.

As is, Spring does not allow you to change the HttpStatus types, which are constant [HttpStatus] objects and are considered a well defined standard in the [HTTP 1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.4.5) RFC.

You can however create your own custom HttpStatus type, with a custom code and reason. But if you decide to do that, you should use a code that is not part of the defined standard.

Instead, you might consider following examples of good REST design best practices. A good example article can be found here: [REST Best Practices](https://stormpath.com/blog/spring-mvc-rest-exception-handling-best-practices-part-1/)

Comment: Nope, what this does is: In my initial config with @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND) it returned a JSON response and a http.status 404 and http.reason Not Found. With your modification it return the 404 error page, in that page there is <h1>HTTP Status 404 - Cuz I said so!</h1> the http.status is 404 however, the http reason phrase is still "Not Found" and not "Cuz I said so!". Also I don't want to have the http error page but my Json response body.

Comment: This is working nicely for me, which I have added to the answer. How are you accessing the endpoint URL? Browser, a REST client? Are you using Spring Boot?

Comment: But that is not the point. What I want is to customise the string of the reason phrase. Not the text in response body. Have a look at the image I attached. The text behind the red dot with the "404". This is called the "reason phrase". I want to return a custom reason phrase.

Comment: Which doesn't make sense as the status codes are a well defined standard. If what you want is to make a custom status code, you should use a different status number, not included in standard codes and with your own custom reason. This is why there is not a simple way to to change the reason of existing HttpStatus codes - they are constant(s).

Comment: That is not entirely true. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404 Quote: "At the HTTP level, a 404 response code is followed by a human-readable "reason phrase". The HTTP specification suggests the phrase "Not Found"[1] and many web servers by default issue an HTML page that includes both the 404 code and the "Not Found" phrase." This text is just a suggestion. And it's typically referred to as the "404 Not found error" however you can give it a custom reason phrase that is more detailed, like xyz resource not found.

Comment: Then I think creating a custom HTTPStatus will be the direction you would have to go. It seems a bit against the grain for Spring, but probably doable.